Using requestly replace string to reroute a local call to a live test environment
I am using the replace string rule to try and replace a content endpoint call within a test environment and replacing it with my localhost url to be able to use live data from an endpoint to test in my local. For some reason we have one team member that the rule works for but on two other machines with the same rule and believed set up it will not apply the request lyk rule to the page with no error just not working. Why would this happen and work for one person but not another. Same rule same permissions same browser same site. For some reason I can’t get the redirect/replace and I can’t update live changes to the test environment when I should be able to see it live in the test environment because of the replace rule

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you please check the console and see if there are any errors?

@AbhishekSachan no errors in console

It would be difficult to find out then. Check the answer by @Sachin or connect with Support team with in app chat system, the team behind that chat is very supportive.

Firstly, Warm Welcome to the SuperUser community. We'd appreciate more details on the question, like a screenshot of the rule.
This could happen due to different Requestly versions installed on the machines.
You can check the version of any Chrome extension by following these steps --

Go to chrome://extensions
Search "Requestly" in Search Extensions
Click "Details"

Here's a screenshot of the details button of a Chrome Extension installed in my browser

A couple of bugs are introduced in the Replace Rule functionality as part of MV3 Migration.
Check out this Github Issue for more details - https://github.com/requestly/requestly/issues/1690.
